# How to connect to TFS via proxy programmatically?

Tags: c#, tfs

At my company we have recently set up a TeamFoundation proxy to our TeamFoundationServer. I have written a C# app, that connects to the TFS to query various things. Now, I want the app to support connection over the TFS proxy as well. As I am not really familiar with TFS, I am having some difficulties. Ideally, I want the application to only "know" the TFS proxy and have it act just like the normal TFS. Is this even possible?

What I am doing is something like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection projects = 
    new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUriString, 
                                 new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
```

This works fine if `serverUriString` is the TFS (e.g. "http://MyTfs:8080"). When I substitute this with the TFS proxy (e.g. "http://MyTfsProxy:8081") I get some unspecific `TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException`, where at the end it states that a http 404 error occurred. The 404 doesn't make much sense to me, I am able to ping the server, I can connect to it from the browser and Visual Studio acceppts it as well. Do I need to set a connection to the TFS AND the proxy? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AddProxy() method is used to register a list of proxy servers with the TFS server, so that clients can automatically detect & use a proxy server.

If you just want to configure your client to use a proxy server, there is no property to do this. You have to set a registry key or an undocumented environment variable.

For TFS2008 clients, the registry key is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy]
"Enabled"="True"
"Url"="http://someproxy:8081"
```

For TFS2010 clients, the registry key is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy]
"Enabled"="True"
"Url"="http://someproxy:8081"
```

In either TFS version, you can set the undocumented environment variable:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TFSPROXY",http://someproxy:8081);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverName));
server.EnsureAuthenticated();

var versionControlServer = server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.ConfigureProxy(proxyName);
```