# How to use TFS proxy with TFS 2008 SDK

Tags: c#, tfs, proxy

In the TFS 2010 API you can add a proxy via AddProxy as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777138/how-to-connect-to-tfs-via-proxy-programmatically)

We have to use TFS 2008 SDK however so I wonder if it is possible to do something similar with that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AddProxy() method is used to register a list of proxy servers with the TFS server, so that clients can automatically detect & use a proxy server.

TFS2008 does not keep a list of TFS Proxy servers, so it is not possible with the TFS 2008 SDK.

If you just want to configure your client to use a proxy server, there is no property to do this. You have to set a registry key or an undocumented environment variable.

For TFS2008 clients, the registry key is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy]
"Enabled"="True"
"Url"="http://someproxy:8081"
```

For TFS2010 clients, the registry key is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy]
"Enabled"="True"
"Url"="http://someproxy:8081"
```

In either TFS version, you can set the undocumented environment variable:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TFSPROXY",http://someproxy:8081);
```

Comment: I think I have no choice than using this, I found it somewhere else as well. Thanks!